# Creating menus in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have front-end on Symfony2 and top-menu and sidebar-menu on it. How can i do that:

1. Top-menu is a horizontal collection of links. Each link belongs to one bundle. For example, link "SMS" refer to MySMSBundle, and so on.\
2. Sidebar-menu is specific by bundle functionality. For example, sidebar-menu from MySMSBundle will looks like "Send SMS, Inbox, Outbox, etc.".

I wanna control both from MySMSBundle and from each other bundle I will to add.

Are you have any idea, or maybe experience with menus organisation in Symfony2?
Thanks for answering!

**UPD:** On itialization each bundle add to top-menu collection it own link (image and other stuff), On loading certain bundle, that bundle must set "active" menu item. Is it right? How can i do this?

Comment: I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316709/symfony-2-autogenerated-navigation-menus but it seems that no such functionality has been implemented yet. Let me know if you've found anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [KnpMenu](https://github.com/knplabs/KnpMenu) to be very flexible and powerful menu library for PHP. In Symfony it's integrated as [KnpMenuBundle](https://github.com/knplabs/KnpMenuBundle).

Your problem is rather specific and you'll probably need to build your own menu builder.

If you want your bundles to register menu items themselves than I guess you could think about using listeners.

You could also provide a menu configuration file in each bundle. Menu builder would than have a list of bundles using menu and look for menu files in them. For found files it would build the menu.

Also, look at how SonataAdminBundle is doing it.